# Removing old node from puppetdb

Tags: puppet, puppetdb

**Running  Puppet Server open source with Puppet DB 4.8**

I recently changed the name of one of my servers and now have two instances of the same machine on puppetdb.
I am trying to remove the NODE by performing the following command:

```
puppet node deactivate old.server..co.uk
```

but it fails with an error:

```
Error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [certificate revoked for /CN=puppetdbserver]
Error: Try 'puppet help node deactivate' for usage
```

I have verified that the puppetdb server can successfully connect back to the puppet server by running `puppet agent -t` on puppets server and all seems fine. Plus puppetdb is actively being updated by my puppetserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to delete from direct database. I founded a link where say to how delete node from catalog.

https://ask.puppet.com/question/88/how-can-i-purge-exported-resources-from-puppetdb/

Comment: Please include the essentials of the link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

can you try  the command in the below form ?

```
     /usr/bin/puppet node deactivate $host --ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl ## replace the path of your ssl directory if its different from /var/lib/puppet/ssl
```